# Diasable input type number after success Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js function called after dropdown change and create a dynamic rows table and in one column is generated `<input type="number">`. In some cases this input must be disabled. Something like this:

`<input type="number" disabled="true">`

obvious this example is illustrative.

Comment: Try `$(inputSelector).prop('disabled',true)`

Comment: @RayonDabre, thanks. I'm having problems with this. I believe because of dynamic...the element don't found. See a slice of my code (the original is bigger) http://jsfiddle.net/uego57wk/1/

Comment: Just check what `$(':input[name="'+ returns[key].matric +'"]')` returns. Is iit a valid selector ?

Comment: Yes, the string of this return is 2015_3715, for example.

Comment: It is difficult to guess the issue from here. It would be more convenient if you could provide some environment where one could execute it and test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: @RayonDabre Ok but regarding OP's posted code, how could it be more specific? At least, this answer gives relevant method to use

Comment: @A.Wolff, At least one could mention the impacts of using the provided selector. Like which elements it will grab!

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
$(':input[type="number"]').attr('disabled',true);
```